# what is the Projection of a point onto the direction of a unit length vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a point x what would be the projection of point x onto the direction given by unit length vector u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $||proj_{u} x||=\frac{x \cdot u}{||u||}$, but $||u||=1$ so that $||proj_{u} x||=x \cdot u$.